# Does OS X 10.7 support TRIM (SSD)?

Tags: macos, ssd, trim, osx-lion

With OS X 10.6 I had massive problems with an SSD – it became slower and slower with each day. At the end I replaced it with a classical hard disk and it was quite fast again.

Now I want to know if at least OS X 10.7 supports TRIM to prevent SSD performance decreasing over time?

Comment: Everything I've seen shows Lion supporting TRIM for Apple SSDs, but I have yet to see any screenshot or other evidence showing TRIM enabled on a non-Apple supplied SSD.  I would LOVE to see one since I'm hoping to buy an SSD to give new life to my macbook pro.

Comment: I believe it's only Intel SSDs but don't quote me on that

Comment: BTW, I was using a Super Talent Masterdrive SX, which is working fine now on Windows 7 (which has TRIM support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen, official TRIM support is limited to Apple-supplied SSDs, but [Trim Enabler](http://www.groths.org/?page_id=322) still works.  ([Reference Discussion](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1150719))

Comment: No TRIM for me on an Apple SSD after upgrading: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19949/i-upgraded-to-lion-wheres-my-trim-support

Comment: Perhaps they didn't go back and add TRIM support for all SSDs that didn't already have it.  Actually, this is probably the case.  Apple's never exactly been known for continued hardware support.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, OS X Lion says **no TRIM support** for my OCZ Vertex2.

Thankfully this SSD controller has good garbage collection routines. Didn't notice a slowdown on OS X Snow Leopard (10.6), so I'm not too worried.

Comment: Thank you Martijn, this is exactly the kind of evidence I was looking for.  Unfortunate and silly, but useful.

Answer (score 1):

Hi yes Lion does support TRIM, if you look at the link below you can see a post with evidence.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/25/mac-os-x-lion-supports-trim-for-ssds/

Comment: That site shows you can check for TRIM Support under apple menu - About This Mac - More Info - System Report - Serial-ATA.  When I tried this on a mid-2011 Mac Mini running OS X 10.7 and fitted with a 500GB SanDisk Ultra 3D SSD (SDSSDH3-500G-G25), it said "No" there is no TRIM support for that particular drive.  Retailers do say this drive has Trim Command Support, so I think it just means 10.7 is refusing to do it on this (non-Apple) drive. But this drive does have a write cache, which I hope will keep it fast even without TRIM.